# Why always come eslint issue after installing a sharepoint spfx solution

Tags: spfx

Node version - 16.13.0
guli cli - 2.3.0
spfx(microsoft generator) - 1.17.1
typescript : 4.5

every time after creating a solution in react and then i'm bundling it's always show eslint error or this package is not there in the eslint is there any solution or any package i need to install  because many hours i spend to solve this issue and some packages version i need to upgrade or degrade to solve this issue

Comment: Are you able to build (`gulp build`) the solution without any issue? What is the error message exactly? What is the error message while bundling? Can you share the screenshot if possible?